# How does one deal with a cancelled NSURLSessionTask in the completion handler block?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

If I create a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`, and later cancel it before it finishes, the completion block still fires seemingly.

```
let downloadTask = session.downloadTaskWithURL(URL, completionHandler: { location, response, error in 
    ...
}
```

How do I check whether or not the download task was cancelled within this block so that I don't try to operate on the resulting download when there isn't one?

Answer (score 38):

For download task, the completion handler will be called with `nil` value for the `location` and the `code` value of the `URLError` object will be `.cancelled`. For example:

```swift
let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
    if let error = error as? URLError {
        if error.code == .cancelled {
            // canceled
        } else {
            // some other error
        }
        return
    }
    
    // proceed to move file at `location` to somewhere more permanent
}
task.resume()
```

Or look for the `code` value of the `NSError` object of `NSURLErrorCancelled`:

```swift
let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
    if let error = error as NSError? {
        if error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
            // canceled
        } else {
            // some other error
        }
        return
    }
    
    // proceed to move file at `location` to somewhere more permanent
}
task.resume()
```

The process of casting the `error` parameter is the same for data tasks, as the download task above.

For Swift 2, see [previous revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26411524/4).

Comment: What about for a download task? Will the location be nil? Or should I just depend on error?

Comment: Yes, the `location` will be `nil`, but you can just check `error`, and if the `code` is `NSURLErrorCancelled`, you know it's been canceled for one reason or another.